# In chemfig, grouping with \color ineffective, unlike \textcolor

Tags: color, chemfig

Some strange behaviour which contradicts the documentation was encountered when creating a figure of 5-cafeoylquinic acid with `chemfig`. It is stated in the manual that

> The atoms are displayed in tikz nodes which behaves like boxes of TeX and it is as if these atoms were put in a group. Therefore, the color change remains local to the atom.

An example is given why writing `O\color{red}H` doesn't work and why `O{\color{red}H}` should be used instead. A remark says,

> The same effect can be obtained with \textcolor.

The following code yields the desired output (Win7 TeXLive 2013 with chemfig 1.0g, rev. 32270):

```
\chemfig{
    [:30]HO-*6(-=-(-=[::-60]-[::60](=[2]O)-[:-30]{\color{red}O}>
    *6(--(([6]<OH)-(-[:30]OH)=[6]
    \textcolor{red}{O}
    )--(<:OH)-(<HO)-)
    )=-(-HO)=)
    }
```

[image: 5-cafeoylquinic acid]

However, when I try to invoke an equivalent colouring with simple `{\color{red}O}`, something odd occurs (line 4):

```
\chemfig{
    [:30]HO-*6(-=-(-=[::-60]-[::60](=[2]O)-[:-30]{\color{red}O}>
    *6(--(([6]<OH)-(-[:30]OH)=[6]
    {\color{red}O}
    )--(<:OH)-(<HO)-)
    )=-(-HO)=)
    }
```

[image: 5-cafeoylquinic acid with misplaced O]

It had worked with the middle “O” but failed with the last one! Why does the presumably equivalent function act the ape?

Comment: You can also write `\color{red}{o}`. It is important to put `O` inside braces to avoid two atoms, the first `\color{red}` and the second `O`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It works with two set of curly braces (changed the color to blue):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\begin{document}
\chemfig{
    [:30]HO-*6(-=-(-=[::-60]-[::60](=[2]O)-[:-30]{\color{red}O}>
    *6(--(([6]<OH)-(-[:30]OH)=[6]
    {{\color{blue}O}}
    )--(<:OH)-(<HO)-)
    )=-(-HO)=)
    }
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Probably the first set of curly braces is removed, when the atom is read as argument. Then TeX automatically removes one pair of braces.

Comment: Thank you very much, I would have never guessed the ungrouping internal routine!